# Why does my text bounce up a line when show/hide menu is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why does my para text bounce up about one line when the show/hide menu is clicked to display the para text? My guess is it's padding or margin or something.

```js
 $(document).on('click touchstart', '.button', function() {
   $('.target-button[data-trigger="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').slideToggle(100);
 });
```

```css
#main_text {
  float: none;
}
.scripture {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.scripture ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
.scripture li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.scripture a {
  color: white;
}
.scripture h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.scripture h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scripture">
  <UL>
    <li><a id="one" class="button">Expand/Contract</a>
    </li>
  </UL>

  <div class="one">
    <h2>Lively Bones</h2>
    <h3>John 11:1-44</h3>

    <div class="target-button" data-trigger="one" style="display:none;">
      <div id="one1">

        <P>“Ezekiel connected them dry bones, Ezekiel connected them dry bones, Ezekiel connected them dry bones, Now hear the word of the Lord.”</P>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening due to the `.slideToggle(100)` code. Try to simply use `.toggle()`, since the slide doesn't seem to be doing much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could give your .scripture h3 margin-bottom: 0; http://screencast.com/t/EOuMgTpM

That should take care of it.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.target-button p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I believe this is related to how jQuery determines the height of the hidden element you are calling the slideToggle on.